# Will apple allow app updates that don't target the iPhone5?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, ios6, iphone-5

Since the new iPhone5 is coming out, will apple allow you to upload an app update without making it run at the full iPhone5 screen size? Will they let you upload an app that runs letterboxed on the new phone?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as you don't provide a Default-568h@2x.png launch image, your app will not run in the new resolution and Apple will allow it **for the time being**.